# Error:(30, 0): Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9]

Tags: android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, classpath, build.gradle

I'm new to android, currently encountering a seemingly endless supply of random errors while going through tutorials.
Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to set up dependencies. I'm not sure what my dependencies should look like and whether they should be different for different projects, but when I try to import:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
```

I am getting the `Error:(30, 0): Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler` message.

[Screenshot of the error](https://gyazo.com/af395f0c9d10079b25309c9c630c97a5)

How do I set up dependencies for simple projects? Is there a popular, up-to-date source to sort these kinds of issues out?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'`is a **project** dependency, not an **module** dependency, so you are placing it wrong.

Check your build.gradle project configuration at your project root directory. If there is a `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'` there as dependency that's all you need.